Different behavior of default transformer and XSLT identity transform
I have the below XML:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x:books xmlns:x="urn:collection" xmlns:p="urn:property">
  <book id="bk001">
    <p:author>Writer</p:author>
    <p:title>The First Book</p:title>
    <p:genre>Fiction</p:genre>
  </book>
</x:books>

which is parsed with a namespace-unaware parser:
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newDefaultInstance(); // JDK-default implementation
factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document dom = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));


When it is converted back to string using the default identity transformer...
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newDefaultInstance(); // JDK-default implementation
Transformer tr0 = factory.newTransformer();
Writer w0 = new StringWriter();
tr0.transform(new DOMSource(dom), new StreamResult(w0));

...I get the original XML unchanged (with all the x: and p: namespace prefixes retained).
However, when I try to use an XSLT identity transform to transform it...
<transform version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="no" />
    <template match="*|@*|node()">
        <copy><apply-templates select="*|@*|node()" /></copy>
    </template>
</transform>

Transformer tr1 = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsltString)));
Writer w1 = new StringWriter();
tr1.transform(new DOMSource(dom), new StreamResult(w1));

... I get the following XML (with all namespace prefixes removed):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><books xmlns:p="urn:property" xmlns:x="urn:collection">
  <book id="bk001">
    <author>Writer</author>
    <title>The First Book</title>
    <genre>Fiction</genre>
  </book>
</books>

Considering in my codebase I have no control over how the DOM is created (it could be namespace-aware or unaware, latter in most cases), how can I write an XSLT 1.0 transform that will always retain all XML namespace prefixes?
(Identity transform is an example, I would like to write more complex transformations in the future)
Is there any property that I can set on the TransformerFactory or any changes in the XSLT match="..." attribute that I can perform to achieve this?

Also, the namespaces urn:collection and urn:property are not constant in my inputs, nor is the structure of the XML. I need to write a XSLT transform that would work for any DOM with any structure

But if you do set factory.setNamespaceAware(true); on your DomBuilderFactory and then apply the identity transform, it preserves the namespace prefixes and works as expected, right?

@MadsHansen yes, if the XML is parsed with a namespace-aware builder, the transformed output retains the namespace prefixes from the input XML for both - the default Transformer and the XSLT identity transform.

XSLT is defined to operate on a namespace-aware data model. If you provide it with input that is not namespace-aware, the results are undefined, and you should not be surprised that different processors give different results.
Yes, there's a real problem that when you're handed a DOM, you can't tell whether it's namespace-aware or not. My advice is to consign DOM to the dustbin of history; I know that's not practical, but if you don't, you have to live with its problems.

I assumed the default transformer internally used the same identity transformation logic but seems like there is some special handling for a namespace-unaware DOM, that does not exist for a transformer that is created using XSLT.

What alternative to DOM do you suggest for an application that extracts hundreds of values using XPath queries? Is there any other intermediate format that can be queried using XPath easily?

There are two XSLT processors commonly used in the Java world, Xalan and Saxon, and both of them have an internal tree representation that is much more efficient than DOM (in Saxon, by a factor of five to ten). Supply a StreamSource or SAXSource as input to the transformation, and let the XSLT processor build its own tree.

If you can't control the DomBuilderFactory or it would be too much effort to refactor and ensure that it has factory.setNamespaceAware(true) consistently everywhere, and you said that it preserves namespaces when you serialize as a string with the default transormer, then you could create your own function that:

serializes to a string with the default transformer
parses the string with your own DomBuilderFactory that DOES have factory.setNamespaceAware(true)
applies the XSLT identity transform

It wouldn't be the most efficient, but might be the easiest way to ensure that the XML does get parsed namespace-aware before applying your XSLT transform.

Thank you, yes I did consider this. However, it might drastically bring down the performance of a multi-threaded application. The documentation suggests that neither TransformerFactory nor Transformer is thread-safe. But an XSLT can be compiled into a Templates that can be used to create new Transformers in a thread-safe manner. But there doesn't seem to be a way to create new default Transformers without synchronizing on the TransformerFactory
